What error handling would one need to implement on their own to integrate linuxptp's ptp4l and phc2sys into their code?
I am currently working on a project that requires ptp4l and phc2sys synced up with a master clock in order to ensure consistent and accurate time while the application is running. I'm taking over work from previous developers where it seems that they were trying to implement some form of error handling based on the print out messages from ptp4l and phc2sys that would cause them to depending on which application had the error restarting just phc2sys or both. This seemingly has caused issues with maintaining a "lock" with the time.
I've done some digging through that old code and the linuxptp source code and noticed that seemingly the previous engineer might have over reacted to some of the messages that can be produced by the two applications. I now need to determine what if any handling of the "pr_" messages from linuxptp would need to be handling by programs trying to utilize these applications.
My understanding is that mainly ptp connections status are based on the s0, s1, and s2 nominators. Where s0 means there is no lock, s1 means something along the lines of syncing up the slave with the master, and s2 indicates that there is a solid lock with the clocks. Is this really all that I need to be concerned about and should rely on the ptp4l and phc2sys applications to handle themselves?
If anyone has any links that can provide better documenation on these applications other than the manpages that would be greatly appreciated? I am struggling to find much information on the actual message print outs that can come from either application and what if anything the operator should do with such information. I do know that messages like UNCALIBRATED to FOO typically are more of an informational message letting you know the state has changed, but then you get messages like: SLAVE to UNCALIBRATED that is a bit more of a grey area on if anything should be done or not for it.
